# Study range of integral function

Tags: calculus

How can I study the range of this function:
$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x^2-2x+2} \frac{\log(t)}{t^2} dt \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$

Comment: You can evaluate that integral. $dt/t^2 = -d(1/t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts,

\begin{align}
\int_1^{p(x)} \frac {\log(t)}{t^2}\ dt &= \left. \frac {-\log(t)}{t} \right|_1^{p(x)} + \int_1^{p(x)} \frac {1}{t^2}\ dt \\
&= \frac {-\log(p(x))}{p(x)} + \left[ \frac {-1}{t} \right]_1^{p(x)} \\
&= \frac {-\log(p(x))}{p(x)} - \frac {1}{p(x)} + 1 \\
&= \frac {-\log(p(x)) -1 +p(x)}{p(x)} \\
\end{align}